# Can't change aperture on my Canon EOS 5D Mk 2

Tags: canon-5d-mark-ii

I am unable to change the aperture in manual mode. The power switch is in the correct position but although the shutter speed changes, the aperture will not budge from 6.3. 
Any ideas what I might have inadvertently altered?

Comment: What lens is attached to your camera? It wouldn't happen to be a fixed aperture f/6.3 mirror lens would it?

Comment: Does the aperture change in Av or Tv modes?

Comment: Are you trying to stop down or open up the lens?

Comment: Is f/6.3 the maximum aperture for the lens at the focal length to which you have it zoomed?

Comment: Thanks for your input guys - I've tried with 70-200, 24-70 and 16-35, all with greater and lower f stops. I've tried to step up and down to no effect and it works correctly in both AV and TV modes???

Answer (score 3):

As you wrote that “it works correctly in both AV and TV modes”, where only one value is changed at a time, the following might work:

In full manual mode (»M«), to change the shutter speed, you use the rotating dial on the top right of the camera whereas for the aperture, you use the large dial to the right of the display. To be able to use that dial, the on-off-switch has to be set to the position above “on” which has a pointing line on top of it which leads to the dial.

As you stated that “[t]he power switch is in the correct position”, the above should work.
If it still doesn’t, please check whether the dial works in other scenarios such as flickering through your images. If it doesn’t—while the power switch is in the correct state—please contact Canon or others for repair.

[image: Dial and power switch position]

You can also find an explanation of how to change the settings in the manual that can be found [on Canon’s support page for the EOS 5D Mark 2](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/cameras/support-dslr/eos-5d-mark-ii)